# sendding byte[] into a KvmSerializable class

Tags: java, android, serialization, arrays, ksoap2

how I can to send a byte [] array inside a class that implements KvmSerializable in Ksoap2 on android?.
when running the application I get the following error:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Can not serialize

my code is this:

```
SoapSerializationEnvelope env = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
env.dotNet = false;
env.xsd = SoapSerializationEnvelope.XSD;
env.enc = SoapSerializationEnvelope.ENC;
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

Car car= new Car();
byte[] bytes = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
car.setBytes(bytes);
PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
pi.setName("car");
pi.setValue(car);
pi.setType(car.getClass());
request.addProperty(pi);
env.setOutputSoapObject(request);
env.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "Car", car.getClass());
```

the Car class:

```
public class Car implements KvmSerializable{

    private byte[] bytes;

    public void setBytes(byte[] bytes) {
        this.bytes= bytes;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getProperty(int arg0) {
        switch(arg0){
            case 0:
                return bytes;

        }

         return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getPropertyCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public void getPropertyInfo(int ind, Hashtable ht, PropertyInfo info) {
        switch(ind){
                case 0:
                    info.type = MarshalBase64.BYTE_ARRAY_CLASS;
                    info.name = "bytes";
                    break;

                default:break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void setProperty(int ind, Object val) {
        switch(ind){
                case 0:
                    bytes = (byte[])val;
                    break;

        }

    }

}
```

anyone can help me?

thanks

Comment: Do you need to have getBytes() on Car?  Also can you please paste the stack trace?

Answer (score 1):

You should add mapping with marshaller for class `byte[]`. For example:
`env.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "Car", byte[].class, new MarshalBase64());`

Or create custom marshaller for your class `Car`, which would write this object and map this marshaller to Car:
`env.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "Car", car.getClass(), new CustomMarshaller());`

Edit: Or you can encode `byte[]` to  `base64` string by hand and return `String` from `getProperty`.

Comment: thank you very much for your help esentsov and hack_on, I used the line env.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "Car", car.getClass(), new CustomMarshaller()), now I have no errors

Comment: Now I have another question, could you help me?, the link is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17927229/sendding-list-into-a-kvmserializable-class