# sendding List into a KvmSerializable class

Tags: java, android, list, serialization, ksoap2

how I can to send a List of java.util.List inside a class that implements KvmSerializable in Ksoap2 on android?. when running the application I get the following error:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Can not serialize

my code is this:

```
SoapSerializationEnvelope env = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
env.dotNet = false;
env.xsd = SoapSerializationEnvelope.XSD;
env.enc = SoapSerializationEnvelope.ENC;
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

Car car= new Car();
byte[] bytes = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
car.setBytes(bytes);
List<Door> list = new ArrayList<Door>();
car.setList(list);
PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
pi.setName("car");
pi.setValue(car);
pi.setType(car.getClass());
request.addProperty(pi);
env.setOutputSoapObject(request);
env.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "Car", byte[].class, new MarshalBase64());
```

the Car class:

```
public class Car implements KvmSerializable{

    private byte[] bytes;
    private List<Door> list;

    public void setBytes(byte[] bytes) {
        this.bytes= bytes;
    }

    public void setList(List<Door> list) {
        this.list= list;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getProperty(int arg0) {
        switch(arg0){
            case 0:
                return bytes;
            case 1:
                return list;

        }

         return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getPropertyCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 2
    }

    @Override
    public void getPropertyInfo(int ind, Hashtable ht, PropertyInfo info) {
        switch(ind){
                case 0:
                    info.type = MarshalBase64.BYTE_ARRAY_CLASS;
                    info.name = "bytes";
                    break;
                 case 1
                    info.type = List.class;
                    info.name = "list";
                    break;

                default:break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void setProperty(int ind, Object val) {
        switch(ind){
                case 0:
                    bytes = (byte[])val;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    list= (List<Door>)val;
                    break;

        }

    }

}
```

the Door class implements KvmSerializable, anyone can help me?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to make class serializable in ksoap2:

1. Create marshall object for this class and `addMapping` for it
2. Implement interface `KvmSerializable`
3. `SoapObject` and `Vector` serializable by default.

`List` does not match any of this condition, so you get an error.
You can create custom marshall object for class `List` or create custom class which would implement `List` interface and `KvmSerializable`. Or you can use  `Vector` (or may be even convert your object to SoapObject by calling `addProperty` and `addSoapObject`).

Comment: thank you very much, I am beginner in ksoap2 and I do not know how to do that you tell me, could you tell me how do?, or write the link of a website that has this information?

Comment: Here is some information: [link](https://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/CodingTipsAndTricks).